# Ignore client certificate popup for a click once landing page - but still require cert for service

Tags: wcf, ssl, iis, clickonce

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS with a default .aspx file that serves as the landing page for a clickonce application. The .svc file and .aspx file are in the same root directory of the application: i.e. the following folder structure:

```
MyService
 --  MyService.svc
 --  Default.aspx
 --  Web.config
```

If I browse MyService and view Default.aspx (my click once landing page) from IIS, I **do not** want to be prompted for a client cert, as the client cert is actually selected from the click once directly and attached to the call of the WCF service (i.e. `client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = UserCertificate;`).

I can get around this in IIS Manager by setting MyService application to **Ignore** client certs and setting MyService.svc to **Accept** client certs. This all works as expected (browsing to Default.aspx doesn't prompt me but browsing to the .svc does), but for deployment & testing reasons, I'd like to automate this in the Web.config. I've tried the following but with no luck.

```
<location path="MyService">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <access sslFlags="None" />
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

```
<location path="MyService.svc">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert" />
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm assuming by setting MyService to `"None"` initially messes it up.

I also ran into similar issues when attempting to move my svc to another folder and having it as a sub application in IIS.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: After you make changes in IIS Manager as you see fit ... open the path in file explorer and check the web.config. It will have all the changes you made. You should be able to copy that section and paste it for your testing scenario web.config

Comment: @MuqeetKhan That doesn't work. I am not seeing any changes to the web.config when navigating to it in Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by adding a custom action in my Advanced Installer project that wrote the XML configuration into the ApplicationHost.config using something along the lines of

```
    using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
        {
            var config = manager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

            try
            {
                ConfigurationSection accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", site);

                if (accessSection != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Opened app host config successfully.");
                    accessSection["sslFlags"] = @"None";
                }

                accessSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", "Default Web Site/MyService/MyService.svc");

                if (accessSection != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Opened app host config successfully.");
                    accessSection["sslFlags"] = @"Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert";
                }

                manager.CommitChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully committed changes");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to open the app host config.");
            }
        }
```